# angular 6 template with async pipe

Tags: json, angular, templates, asynchronous, pipe

I have the following template code in a component:

```
   <div *ngIf="current_user | async as cu">
        <a href="#" *ngIf="!(cu.id > 0)">Sign In [{{cu | json}}]</a>
    </div>
```

the json pipe outputs:

```
{ user: { id: 1 }}
```

but the async pipe seemingly doesn't. The anchor tag always gets shown.
It should be hidden if the id > 0 (user is signed in).

Comment: your html seems wrong `*ngIf="!cu.id > 0">` ?

Comment: also, could you please include more explanation on your question?

Comment: id = 1. So the `if` will evaluate to false?! Therefore no anchor tag is shown. `!1 > 0` = `0 > 0` = `false`

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @ferdtomale That still evaluates to false. `cu.id` IS greater than 0, so you have `!(true)`

Comment: it does evaluate to false - the anchor tag should not be shown then but it always does get shown.

Comment: Seems to work fine in a StackBlitz demo? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8r6fx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: are you sure your id is  number? or is text?

Comment: You could try `*ngIf="cu.user.id <= 0"`. The JSON output indicates that `cu` has a `user` property which has the `id` property.

Comment: figured it out. cu is an object. it should have been "!cu.user.id > 0". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<div *ngIf="current_user | async as cu">
  <a href="#" *ngIf="!(cu.user.id > 0)">Sign In [{{cu | json}}]</a>
</div>
```